# pyinstaller executable file behaving differently on different computers

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made an executable file with pyinstaller and when I run it on the computer i created it on, it works perfectly however when i run it on any other computer, it seems to be skipping lines of code and therefore failing. It is using sockets and somewhere it messes up maybe when the server sends data? It seems to be skipping some lines like the print statement after I open a file (f=open('filename','rb')) and I know I can write a file in that directory because it has worked with other programs.  I have no idea what the issue could be because it works on the original computer but not the rest.  Is there any reason for this discrepancy between computers? I am new to socket programming so any help to fix my code as well would be helpful too.

Client:

```
s=socket.socket()
host='10.0.0.9'
port=1111
while True:
    try:
        s.connect((host,port))
        s.send(save_dest)
        break
    except:
        pass
print 'trying to copy...'
try:
    print 'file destination'
    #prints file destination
    file=open('file destination,'wb')
    #does not print 'file opened'
    print 'file opened'
    l=s.recv(1024)
    while True:
        #prints l here however it is on the same line as print 'file destination' which I do not understand why
        print l
        file.write(l)
        #does not print 'okkk'
        print 'okkk'
        l=s.recv(1024)
        if l[len(l)-5:]=='~end~':
            break
    #does not run code here
    print 'success'
    s.send('successfully copied file to'+'file name')
    file.close()
except:
    #throughs exception somewhere but idk where
    print 'failed'
    s.send('failed to copy file')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read how to ask a question and then include a CMVE (Complete, Minimal,Verifiable Example)

Comment: @Foon is CMVE a snippet of my code?

Comment: Read the help section (specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) an MCVE is the smallest section of your code that has the problem, with expected output, actual output (including the error message), and anything else needed for someone to replicate the problem

Comment: A couple of other suggestions: 1) try installing python by hand on another system and running your script there (i.e. take pyinstaller out of the equation).  2) change except: to except Exception as e: and then print e inside your exception handling routine (and you should be catching specific exceptions versus catch-all, but that's a different topic)
3) As written s.send(save_dest) will throw an exception because save_dest isn't defined; not sure if you left that out or what.

Comment: @Foon oh yea i took out other parts of the code so save_dest is just the destination

Comment: nvm i figured it out. the server was sending data too fast and the client was recieving all of it at one time instead at 2 different times.